# issue with nested route in Rails 5.1 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building an application for students to register an absence during a exam.

my routes look like this:

```
resources :users do
  resources :absences
end
```

the form to create an absence looks like this:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @absence] do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :course_id, "Vak" %>
  <%= f.select :course_id, options_for_courses, label: "Vak" %>
  <%= f.label :date, "Datum" %>
  <%= f.text_field :date %>
  <%= f.submit "Afwezigheid aanvragen" %>
<% end %>
```

the Absence model looks like this:

```
class Absence < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  belongs_to :user
end
```

the User model looks like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many :absences
end
```

The AbsencesController looks like this:

```
class AbsencesController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def new
    @user = current_user
    @absence = current_user.absences.build
  end

  def create
    @absence = Absence.create(absence_params)
    if @absence.save
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Afwezigheid succesvol aangevraagd"
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Er was een probleem met het registreren van de afwezigheid"
    render :new
  end
end
```

But when I try to register an absence, I get an error in the form:
The error log looks like this:

```
Started POST "/users/2/absences" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-21 09:51:55 +0200
Processing by AbsencesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"esW1HeKf+VG8+RC4Zm2F7d8BFewddk6aIssj0Y90s+UC4oTUxpO1iw9hR9M94Jfov5bjeB0aQPRHG0qvENO3Tg==", "absence"=>{"course_id"=>"2", "date"=>"27/09/2017"}, "commit"=>"Afwezigheid aanvragen", "user_id
"=>"2"}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Course Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "courses".* FROM "courses" WHERE "courses"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendering absences/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered absences/new.html.erb within layouts/application (145.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 616ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)



ActionView::Template::Error - undefined method `absences_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fb911af0420>:0x007fb90baab5d8>
Did you mean?  asset_path:
  actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:230:in `polymorphic_method'
  actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:138:in `polymorphic_path'
  actionview (5.1.3) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:472:in `apply_form_for_options!'
  actionview (5.1.3) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:440:in `form_for'
```

I'm not sure what's going on, have I missed something?

thanks for your help,

Anthony

Comment: Please paste the complete log

Comment: try `@absence = @user.absences.build` instead of  `@absence = current_user.absences.build`

Comment: @Oscar Luza, that didn't fix the issue, I'm getting the same error

Comment: @Deep I copied the log

Comment: Once just try changing the `@user` to `current_user` on the `form` view. This should solve your issue.

Comment: @Toontje I found your problem, check my answer

Comment: hi Deep, yes, this fixed the previous error. There still is a problem hower in the create method of AbsencesController. I don't think this is correct: absence = Absence.create(absence_params). When check the absence object, the user_id property is nil

Comment: @Toontje I have updated the answer

Comment: @Toontje as you can see at your your it tries to render new path` Rendering absences/new.html.erb within layouts/application`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error while creating your object and you are doing `render :new` which is rendering the form again but with `@user` as `nil`. So what happens that `<%= form_for [nil, @absence] do |f| %>` makes the path as `absences_path` which is not present. So either fetch `@user` in create action too or just use `current_user` everywhere. Like this:

```
 def new
   @user = current_user # You may remove this
   @absence = current_user.absences.build
 end

 def create
   @absence = Absence.create(absence_params)
   if @absence.save
     redirect_to root_path, notice: "Afwezigheid succesvol aangevraagd"
   else
     @user = current_user # If you don't want to remove this line from new action then add it here too
     flash[:alert] = "Er was een probleem met het registreren van de afwezigheid"
     render :new
   end
 end
```

And in the `form` if you remove the `@user` from controller then do it like this:

```
<%= form_for [current_user, @absence] do |f| %>
```

**Update:**

To save the object in `create` action change this line:

```
@absence = Absence.create(absence_params)
```

to

```
@absence = current_user.absences.build(absence_params)
```

Your `user_id` was nil because there was no input box or any hidden field for that and that is correct. You just need to build the object again against the `current_user`. And I have changed the `create` to `build` because `create` directly saves the object to database instead you want to build it first and then you are trying to `save` it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks Deep, I changed: absence = Absence.create(absence_params) to  absence = current_user.absences.build(absence_params) and now the absence get created.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting problem in your `create` method when you are rendering the `new` because form doesn't getting the `@user`

add following in your create method & check again

```
@user = current_user
```

Comment: Hi Salil, I added user = current_user in the create method, but when I check the absence object, the user_id property is nil. Therefore I think the problem is this line: absence = Absence.create(absence_params). Maybe I should state this like: absence = user.absences.build(absence_params) ?

Comment: Yeah replace `@absence = Absence.create(absence_params)` with `@user.absences.build(absence_params)`

Answer (score -1):

Okay, you just add return after this line:

```
redirect_to root_path, notice: "Afwezigheid succesvol aangevraagd"
return
```

As your log says, you are trying to render :new template at the end of the method, you need to add return to stop it after redirect_to

or delete that line at the end of your create method

```
    render :new
```

Also change this:
`@absence = current_user.absences.build(absence_params)`

Comment: There is a if else case there so either `redirect` will happen if the object is saved or it will `render` new. And if he deletes `render :new` in case of error the form will not be rendered and it will throw template missing exception.

Comment: `ActionView::Template::Error - undefined method `absences_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fb911af0420>:0x007fb90baab5d8>`. Read the log please

Comment: @Oscar Luza, the problem with ActionView::Template::Error is fixed now. But there is a problem in the create method. For some reason a new absence does not get created. When I check the absence object in the create method, the user_id property is nil